# Error fetching route from 4900ZZLULSQ1 to 4900ZZLUCGN1: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "modes", intValue: nil),

Tags: json, swift

Trying to use the TFL API `https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/\(fromStation)/to/\(toStation)`   to and from station are the id's of the station
https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/4900ZZLULSQ1/to/4900ZZLUGPK1
but get this error when I try to decode the JSON into a swift struct

> Error fetching route from 4900ZZLULSQ1 to 4900ZZLUCGN1: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "modes", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "journeys", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "legs", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "departurePoint", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "modes", intValue: nil) ("modes").", underlyingError: nil))

Some code

```
@Published var routeFetched:Bool = false
@Published var isFetchingRoute:Bool = false
@Published var route: JourneyPlannerResponse? = nil

    @MainActor
    func getRouteDirections(fromStation: String, toStation: String) {
        routeFetched = false
        isFetchingRoute = true
        print("Fetching Route")
        let urlString = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/\(fromStation)/to/\(toStation)"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Failed URL")
            return
        }
        Task {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                if let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Raw Data: " + dataString)
                } else {
                    print("Unable to convert data to string")
                }
                print("Received data from URL")
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let route = try decoder.decode(JourneyPlannerResponse.self, from: data)
                print("Route:", route)
                print("Route decoded successfully")
                isFetchingRoute = false
                routeFetched = true

            } catch {
                print("Error fetching route from \(fromStation) to \(toStation):", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

and then my structs

```
struct Journey: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let startDateTime: String
    let duration: Int
    let arrivalDateTime: String
    let alternativeRoute: Bool
    let legs: [Leg]
    let fare: JourneyFare
}

struct Leg: Codable {
    let duration: Int
    let instruction: Instruction
    let departureTime: String
    let arrivalTime: String
    let departurePoint: StopPoint
    let arrivalPoint: StopPoint
    let path: PathModel
    let routeOptions: [RouteOption]
    let mode: Mode?
    let isDisrupted: Bool
    let hasFixedLocations: Bool
    let scheduledDepartureTime: String
    let scheduledArrivalTime: String
}

struct Instruction: Codable {
    let summary: String
    let detailed: String
    let steps: [String]
}

struct PathModel: Codable {
    let lineString: String
    let stopPoints: [StopPoint]
    let elevation: [Double]
}

struct RouteOption: Codable {
    let name: String
    let directions: [String]
    let lineIdentifier: Identifier
    let direction: String
}

struct Identifier: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let uri: String
    let type: String
    let routeType: String
    let status: String
    let crowding: Crowding?
}

struct Crowding: Codable {
    // Define the properties of Crowding if available in the JSON
    // You can add the necessary properties based on the actual JSON structure
}

struct Mode: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let routeType: String
    let status: String
    let motType: String
    let network: String
}

struct JourneyFare: Codable {
    let totalCost: Int
    let fares: [Fare]
    let caveats: [FareCaveat]
}

struct Fare: Codable {
    let lowZone: Int
    let highZone: Int
    let cost: Int
    let chargeProfileName: String
    let isHopperFare: Bool
    let chargeLevel: String
    let peak: Int
    let offPeak: Int
    let taps: [FareTap]
}

struct FareTap: Codable {
    let atcoCode: String
    let tapDetails: FareTapDetails
}

struct FareTapDetails: Codable {
    let modeType: String
    let validationType: String
    let hostDeviceType: String
    let nationalLocationCode: Int
    let tapTimestamp: String
}

struct FareCaveat: Codable {
    let text: String
}

struct StopPoint: Codable, Hashable {
    let naptanId: String
    let modes: [String]
    let stationNaptan: String
    let lines: [Line1]
    let lineGroup: [LineGroup]
    let lineModeGroups: [LineModeGroup]
    let commonName: String
    let additionalProperties: [AdditionalProperty]
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(naptanId)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: StopPoint, rhs: StopPoint) -> Bool {
        return lhs.naptanId == rhs.naptanId
    }
}
```

My JSON output is
Pretty formatted JSON:

```
{
  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.ItineraryResult, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
  "stopMessages" : [

  ],
  "journeys" : [
    {
      "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Journey, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "alternativeRoute" : false,
      "startDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
      "legs" : [
        {
          "obstacles" : [

          ],
          "departureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
          "arrivalPoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLUCGN1",
            "commonName" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLUCGN",
            "icsCode" : "1000056",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12440792883999999,
            "lat" : 51.513064198499997
          },
          "hasFixedLocations" : true,
          "scheduledDepartureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
          "departurePoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLULSQ3",
            "commonName" : "Leicester Square Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLULSQ",
            "icsCode" : "1000135",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12768234237000001,
            "lat" : 51.511587786420002
          },
          "path" : {
            "elevation" : [

            ],
            "lineString" : "[[51.51154999963, -0.12763933877],[51.51187123768, -0.12684925791],[51.51211228092, -0.12617643205],[51.51250310040, -0.12531009695],[51.51302757941, -0.12436616467]]",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Path, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "stopPoints" : [
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "940GZZLUCGN",
                "type" : "StopPoint",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "name" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
                "uri" : "\/StopPoint\/940GZZLUCGN"
              }
            ]
          },
          "instruction" : {
            "steps" : [

            ],
            "detailed" : "Piccadilly line towards Arnos Grove",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "summary" : "Piccadilly line to Covent Garden"
          },
          "routeOptions" : [
            {
              "directions" : [
                "Arnos Grove Underground Station"
              ],
              "lineIdentifier" : {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "piccadilly",
                "type" : "Line",
                "crowding" : {
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
                },
                "name" : "Piccadilly",
                "uri" : "\/Line\/piccadilly"
              },
              "name" : "Piccadilly",
              "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.RouteOption, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
              "direction" : "Outbound"
            }
          ],
          "mode" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "status" : "Unknown",
            "id" : "tube",
            "motType" : "1",
            "type" : "Mode",
            "routeType" : "Unknown",
            "name" : "tube",
            "network" : "tfl"
          },
          "plannedWorks" : [

          ],
          "arrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
          "disruptions" : [

          ],
          "duration" : 0,
          "isDisrupted" : false,
          "scheduledArrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
          "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
        }
      ],
      "duration" : 0,
      "arrivalDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:18:00",
      "fare" : {
        "caveats" : [
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "<p>Fares between two stations may vary depending on the direction of travel, time of day and day of the week.<\/p><p>We charge higher fares at the busiest times of the day (usually between 06:30 and 09:30, and between 16:00 and 19:00, Monday to Friday).<\/p><p>When you pay as you go, you must touch your contactless or Oyster card on a yellow reader at the start and end of your journey.<\/p><p>Some journeys are charged via Zone 1 regardless of the route taken.<\/p><p>If your journey avoids Zone 1 and you see a pink card reader when changing trains, touch your contactless or Oyster card on it to pay the right fare.<\/p>",
            "type" : "allRailModes"
          },
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "The price shown is a single adult pay as you go fare.",
            "type" : "generic"
          }
        ],
        "fares" : [
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Fare, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "cost" : 280,
            "isHopperFare" : false,
            "chargeLevel" : "Peak",
            "peak" : 280,
            "lowZone" : 1,
            "taps" : [
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTap, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "atcoCode" : "940GZZLULSQ",
                "tapDetails" : {
                  "modeType" : "Rail",
                  "hostDeviceType" : "Gate",
                  "validationType" : "None",
                  "nationalLocationCode" : 631,
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTapDetails, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                  "tapTimestamp" : "2023-06-29T19:18:00+01:00"
                }
              },
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTap, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "atcoCode" : "940GZZLUCGN",
                "tapDetails" : {
                  "modeType" : "Rail",
                  "hostDeviceType" : "Gate",
                  "validationType" : "None",
                  "nationalLocationCode" : 553,
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTapDetails, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                  "tapTimestamp" : "2023-06-29T19:18:00+01:00"
                }
              }
            ],
            "offPeak" : 270,
            "highZone" : 1,
            "chargeProfileName" : "Standard peak\/off peak"
          }
        ],
        "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.JourneyFare, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "totalCost" : 280
      }
    },
    {
      "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Journey, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "alternativeRoute" : false,
      "startDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:20:00",
      "legs" : [
        {
          "obstacles" : [

          ],
          "departureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:20:00",
          "arrivalPoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLUCGN1",
            "commonName" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLUCGN",
            "icsCode" : "1000056",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12440792883999999,
            "lat" : 51.513064198499997
          },
          "hasFixedLocations" : true,
          "scheduledDepartureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:20:00",
          "departurePoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLULSQ3",
            "commonName" : "Leicester Square Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLULSQ",
            "icsCode" : "1000135",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12768234237000001,
            "lat" : 51.511587786420002
          },
          "path" : {
            "elevation" : [

            ],
            "lineString" : "[[51.51154999963, -0.12763933877],[51.51187123768, -0.12684925791],[51.51211228092, -0.12617643205],[51.51250310040, -0.12531009695],[51.51302757941, -0.12436616467]]",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Path, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "stopPoints" : [
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "940GZZLUCGN",
                "type" : "StopPoint",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "name" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
                "uri" : "\/StopPoint\/940GZZLUCGN"
              }
            ]
          },
          "instruction" : {
            "steps" : [

            ],
            "detailed" : "Piccadilly line towards Cockfosters",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "summary" : "Piccadilly line to Covent Garden"
          },
          "routeOptions" : [
            {
              "directions" : [
                "Cockfosters Underground Station"
              ],
              "lineIdentifier" : {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "piccadilly",
                "type" : "Line",
                "crowding" : {
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
                },
                "name" : "Piccadilly",
                "uri" : "\/Line\/piccadilly"
              },
              "name" : "Piccadilly",
              "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.RouteOption, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
              "direction" : "Outbound"
            }
          ],
          "mode" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "status" : "Unknown",
            "id" : "tube",
            "motType" : "1",
            "type" : "Mode",
            "routeType" : "Unknown",
            "name" : "tube",
            "network" : "tfl"
          },
          "plannedWorks" : [

          ],
          "arrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:21:00",
          "disruptions" : [

          ],
          "duration" : 1,
          "isDisrupted" : false,
          "scheduledArrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:21:00",
          "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
        }
      ],
      "duration" : 1,
      "arrivalDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:21:00",
      "fare" : {
        "caveats" : [
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "<p>Fares between two stations may vary depending on the direction of travel, time of day and day of the week.<\/p><p>We charge higher fares at the busiest times of the day (usually between 06:30 and 09:30, and between 16:00 and 19:00, Monday to Friday).<\/p><p>When you pay as you go, you must touch your contactless or Oyster card on a yellow reader at the start and end of your journey.<\/p><p>Some journeys are charged via Zone 1 regardless of the route taken.<\/p><p>If your journey avoids Zone 1 and you see a pink card reader when changing trains, touch your contactless or Oyster card on it to pay the right fare.<\/p>",
            "type" : "allRailModes"
          },
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "The price shown is a single adult pay as you go fare.",
            "type" : "generic"
          }
        ],
        "fares" : [
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Fare, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "cost" : 280,
            "isHopperFare" : false,
            "chargeLevel" : "Peak",
            "peak" : 280,
            "lowZone" : 1,
            "taps" : [
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTap, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "atcoCode" : "940GZZLULSQ",
                "tapDetails" : {
                  "modeType" : "Rail",
                  "hostDeviceType" : "Gate",
                  "validationType" : "None",
                  "nationalLocationCode" : 631,
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTapDetails, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                  "tapTimestamp" : "2023-06-29T19:20:00+01:00"
                }
              },
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTap, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "atcoCode" : "940GZZLUCGN",
                "tapDetails" : {
                  "modeType" : "Rail",
                  "hostDeviceType" : "Gate",
                  "validationType" : "None",
                  "nationalLocationCode" : 553,
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareTapDetails, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                  "tapTimestamp" : "2023-06-29T19:21:00+01:00"
                }
              }
            ],
            "offPeak" : 270,
            "highZone" : 1,
            "chargeProfileName" : "Standard peak\/off peak"
          }
        ],
        "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.JourneyFare, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "totalCost" : 280
      }
    },
    {
      "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Journey, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
      "alternativeRoute" : false,
      "startDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
      "legs" : [
        {
          "obstacles" : [

          ],
          "departureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
          "arrivalPoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLUCGN1",
            "commonName" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLUCGN",
            "icsCode" : "1000056",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12440792883999999,
            "lat" : 51.513064198499997
          },
          "hasFixedLocations" : true,
          "scheduledDepartureTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
          "departurePoint" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.StopPoint, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "platformName" : "",
            "individualStopId" : "9400ZZLULSQ3",
            "commonName" : "Leicester Square Underground Station",
            "naptanId" : "940GZZLULSQ",
            "icsCode" : "1000135",
            "placeType" : "StopPoint",
            "additionalProperties" : [

            ],
            "lon" : -0.12768234237000001,
            "lat" : 51.511587786420002
          },
          "path" : {
            "elevation" : [

            ],
            "lineString" : "[[51.51154999963, -0.12763933877],[51.51187123768, -0.12684925791],[51.51211228092, -0.12617643205],[51.51250310040, -0.12531009695],[51.51302757941, -0.12436616467]]",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Path, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "stopPoints" : [
              {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "940GZZLUCGN",
                "type" : "StopPoint",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "name" : "Covent Garden Underground Station",
                "uri" : "\/StopPoint\/940GZZLUCGN"
              }
            ]
          },
          "instruction" : {
            "steps" : [

            ],
            "detailed" : "Piccadilly line towards Cockfosters",
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Instruction, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "summary" : "Piccadilly line to Covent Garden"
          },
          "routeOptions" : [
            {
              "directions" : [
                "Cockfosters Underground Station"
              ],
              "lineIdentifier" : {
                "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
                "routeType" : "Unknown",
                "status" : "Unknown",
                "id" : "piccadilly",
                "type" : "Line",
                "crowding" : {
                  "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
                },
                "name" : "Piccadilly",
                "uri" : "\/Line\/piccadilly"
              },
              "name" : "Piccadilly",
              "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.RouteOption, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
              "direction" : "Outbound"
            }
          ],
          "mode" : {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Identifier, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "status" : "Unknown",
            "id" : "tube",
            "motType" : "1",
            "type" : "Mode",
            "routeType" : "Unknown",
            "name" : "tube",
            "network" : "tfl"
          },
          "plannedWorks" : [

          ],
          "arrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
          "disruptions" : [

          ],
          "duration" : 0,
          "isDisrupted" : false,
          "scheduledArrivalTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
          "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.Leg, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
        }
      ],
      "duration" : 0,
      "arrivalDateTime" : "2023-06-29T18:23:00",
      "fare" : {
        "caveats" : [
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "<p>Fares between two stations may vary depending on the direction of travel, time of day and day of the week.<\/p><p>We charge higher fares at the busiest times of the day (usually between 06:30 and 09:30, and between 16:00 and 19:00, Monday to Friday).<\/p><p>When you pay as you go, you must touch your contactless or Oyster card on a yellow reader at the start and end of your journey.<\/p><p>Some journeys are charged via Zone 1 regardless of the route taken.<\/p><p>If your journey avoids Zone 1 and you see a pink card reader when changing trains, touch your contactless or Oyster card on it to pay the right fare.<\/p>",
            "type" : "allRailModes"
          },
          {
            "$type" : "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.JourneyPlanner.FareCaveat, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "text" : "The price shown is a single adult pay as you go fare.",
            "type" : "generic"
          }
        ],
        "fares" : [
```

My JSON was too long so here is the shortened version

I have literally no idea why this error occurs because I have decoded other TFL related urls and it all works smooth

Comment: Your type `StopPoint` contains a property `modes` but that isn't in the json.